# edit form submitting to the wrong url and remote: true failing to be picked-up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, simple-form

This has been driving me nuts because it doesnt seem to make any sense.

I want to do something relatively simple.

Display an edit form in a modal on the index page.

I have the following code looping through a collection of sites

```
<%= render(@sites) %>
<%= will_paginate @sites %>
```

Within the sites partial i have the following form hidden away

```
<%= simple_form_for site, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :matter  %>
  <%= f.submit "Save", :class => "button gr thirt", id: "site_save" %>
<% end %>
```

instead of generating the expected HTML i get the following, linking to the show action, am I missing something fundamental here?

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/sites/1" class="simple_form edit_site" data-remote="true"  method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
</form>
```

Comment: post the controller method for this action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looping through a collection of @sites, a results returned by a call to Site.all
so the object being served to the above form is one of the |site|'s contained within @sites

If you serve a form_for form with a an object retrieved from the database or a 'new record' object like Site.new, it will automatically differentiate and modify the route etc accordingly between the create and the update action.

The site object contained in the @sites block was not recognizable by the form_for.  So a quick re factor to request an edit from via ajax, and provide the form with the instance variable created by the edit action (@site = Site.find(params[:id]) ) was recognizable by the form_for helper and meant that the submit action, accordingly adjusted to the correct route.